# Ruby delegation for an object without overriding constructor

Tags: ruby, delegation

One example of Ruby delegation is to use a SimpleDelegator:

```
class FooDecorator < SimpleDelegator
  include ActiveModel::Model
  # ...
end
```

That's very convenient, since anything not responded to by FooDecorator is passed to the underlying object.

**But this overwrites the constructor's signature,** which makes it incompatible with things like `ActiveModel::Model` that expect to see a particular signature.

Another example of Ruby delegation is to use  `Forwardable`:

```
class Decorator
  include ActiveModel::Model
  extend Forwardable

  attr_accessor :members
  def_delegator  :@members, :bar, :baz
  def_delegators :@members, :a, :b, :c
end
```

**But now you have to be explicit about which methods you want to delegate,** which is brittle.

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds, where I...

- don't tamper with the constructor
- get pass-through delegation for any equivalently named method on the delegated object

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [Delegator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html) docs? You could basically re-implement your own Delegator subclass with the `__getobj__` and `__setobj__` methods. Or, you could just subclass SimpleDelegator and specify your own constructor that calls `super(obj_to_delegate_to)`, no?

You could always just implement `method_missing` on your decorator and pass through any not-found method to the underlying object, too.

Edit: Here we go. The use of an intermediate inherited class breaks the `super()` chaining, allowing you to wrap the class as desired:

```
require 'active_model'
require 'delegate'

class Foo
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :bar
end

class FooDelegator < Delegator
  def initialize
    # Explicitly don't call super
  end

  def wrap(obj)
    @obj = obj
    self
  end

  def __getobj__
    @obj
  end
end

class FooDecorator < FooDelegator
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def name
    self.class.name
  end
end

decorator = FooDecorator.new.wrap(Foo.new bar: "baz")
puts decorator.name #=> "decorator"
puts decorator.bar  #=> "bar"
```

Comment: If I specify my own constructor, then I've broken `ActiveModel::Model` by overriding it, so that won't work. AFAICT using `Delegator` at all requires calling `super`, which means writing a constructor, which violates the first bullet.

I guess I could completely rewrite Delegator for my own purposes (it's not a very big class) but that's work I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how it doesn't work with ActiveModel? It shouldn't be all that hard to work around.

Comment: @ChrisHeald: `ActiveModel::Model` injects [this signature](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/model.rb#L78-L84) for #initialize. If I want the delegating object to be an `ActiveModel::Model` it can't touch #initialize; otherwise it will break the signature (bad!) or it'll be reimplementing `ActiveModel::Model` (bad!).

Comment: You're going to have to make a module that does what `Delegator` does with `method_missing`. I'm not aware of a module that exists that does this already. Probably because it's inadvisable to mix a delegate object with any other responsibility.

Comment: Ah, per your latest edit, I see what you're trying to do. Should be addressable. How exactly do you expect to be able to pass in the underlying object, though? Your decorator shouldn't be a model, it should be wrapping a model. Also, have you looked at [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper)?

Comment: @Thanatos: It's entirely possible that the best answer to this question is "that's a bad idea and you shouldn't do that". :)

Comment: @ChrisHeald: Some method for that purpose is fine (e.g. `__setobj__`), or a class method would also work (e.g. `FooDecorator.decorate(foo)`).

Comment: Okay, but why are you wanting your decorator to have model behavior, rather than having it wrap a model?

Comment: @JohnFeminella: I don't see any reason you _have_ to use the Delegator initializer. If you let `ActiveModel::Model` override it, that should be fine. Just be sure to override `__getobj__` to return the delegate object you want to use.

Comment: @ChrisHeald: In this particular example I'm extracting some model code that doesn't really need to be in a model all the time, only in a very specific case. It does wrap a model, but it also needs to perform its own validation (for instance). Composition over inheritance.

Comment: I have to run out to do an errand, but I should have a solution when I get back. It basically involves an intermediate class to inherit from which eats the initialize chain.

Comment: Your suggestion of Draper looks like it would be quite helpful. In particular their `delegate_all` method does exactly what I'm describing here.

Comment: I'm back and have updated my answer with my solution. I think it should do what you want!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want ActiveModel::Model? Do you truly need all of the features?

Could you merely do the same thing?

```
extend  ActiveModel::Naming
extend  ActiveModel::Translation
include ActiveModel::Validations
include ActiveModel::Conversion
```

I'm aware that changes to ActiveModel::Model could break your decorator in terms of the expected behavior, but you're coupling pretty tightly to it anyway.

Allowing modules to control constructors is a code smell. Might be ok, but you should second guess it and be well aware of why it does so.

ActiveModel::Model defines `initialize` to expect a hash. I'm not sure how you expect to get the particular object that you want to wrap.
SimpleDelegator uses `__setobj__` inside of it's constructor, so you can use that after including a module that overrides your constructor.

If you want automatic forwarding you can just define the methods you need on your decorator when you set the object. If you can control how your object is created, make a `build` method (or something like that) which calls the `initialize` that needs to be used for ActiveModel::Model and `__setobj__` that's used for SimpleDelegator:

```
require 'delegate'
require 'forwardable'
class FooCollection < SimpleDelegator
  extend Forwardable
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def self.build(hash, obj)
    instance = new(hash)
    instance.send(:set_object, obj)
    instance
  end

  private

  def set_object(obj)
    important_methods = obj.methods(false) - self.class.instance_methods
    self.class.delegate [*important_methods] => :__getobj__
    __setobj__(obj)
  end
end
```

This allows you to used the ActiveModel interface but adds the SingleForwardable module to the singleton class of the decorator which gives you the `delegate` method. All you need to do then is pass it a collection of method names and a method to use to get the object for forwarding.

If you need to include or exclude particular methods, just change the way `important_methods` is created. I didn't think much about that, so double-check what's actually being used there before grabbing this code. For example, once the `set_object` method is called once, you can skip calling it later, but this is built to expect that all wrapped objects have the same interface.

As you pointed out on twitter, the [draper gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) uses the `delegate` method (from ActiveSupport) inside of `method_missing`. With that approach, each missed hit will incur the cost of opening the class and defining the method for forwarding. The upside is that it's lazy and you don't need to calculate which methods need to be forwarded and that hit is only incurred on the first miss; subsequent method calls won't be missed because you're defining that method.
The code I made above will get all those methods and define them at once.

If you need more flexibility and expect your decorator to not be the same type of object you can use SingleForwardable for the same effect but it will define methods for each wrapped instance instead of affecting the decorator class:

```
require 'delegate'
require 'forwardable'
class FooCollection < SimpleDelegator
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def self.build(hash, obj)
    instance = new(hash)
    instance.set_object(obj)
    instance
  end

  def set_object(obj)
    important_methods = obj.methods(false) - self.class.instance_methods
    singleton_class.extend SingleForwardable
    singleton_class.delegate [*important_methods] => :__getobj__
    __setobj__(obj)
  end
end
```

But all of this is using SimpleDelegator and if you're not actually using method_missing, you can cut that out (assuming you've calculated the `important_methods` part correctly:

```
require 'forwardable'
class FooCollection
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def self.build(hash, obj)
    instance = new(hash)
    instance.set_object(obj)
    instance
  end

  def set_object(obj)
    important_methods = obj.methods(false)# - self.class.instance_methods
    singleton_class.extend SingleForwardable
    singleton_class.delegate [*important_methods] => :__getobj__
    __setobj__(obj)
  end

  def __getobj__
    @obj
  end

  def __setobj__(obj)
    __raise__ ::ArgumentError, "cannot forward to self" if self.equal?(obj)
    @obj = obj
  end
end
```

If you do that, however, it kills the use of `super` so you can't override a method defined on your wrapped object and call `super` to get the original value like you can with `method_missing` used in SimpleDelegator.

I wrote [casting](https://github.com/saturnflyer/casting) to add behavior to objects without worrying about wrappers. You can't override methods with it, but if all you're doing is adding new behaviors and new methods, then it will be much simpler to use by just adding a bucket of methods to an existing object. It's worth checking it out. I gave a presentation about the `delegate` and `forwardable` libraries at [RubyConf 2013](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XdVLv5nqvk)